# Unfortunately Stopky has stopped working - bad layout file

Tags: android, xml

I have a problem. Before me it worked, but now I redid activity_main.xml (layout) is not working. I know that as it may activity_main.xml, because before it worked and I changed it. When you open the app appears to me only: Unfortunately Stopky has stopped working .... Please Do not know what to do?

My layout file (activity_main.xml):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTimer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="0:00:000"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="75sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStart"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textTimer"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textTimer"
        android:text="Start" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSplit"
        android:layout_width="95dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnStart"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnStart"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Mezičas" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnResume"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textTimer"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textTimer"
        android:text="Obnovit"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPause"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textTimer"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textTimer"
        android:text="Stop" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSplit2"
        android:layout_width="95dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textTimer"
        android:text="Mezičas"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSplit5"
        android:layout_width="95dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textTimer"
        android:text="Mezičas"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSplit4"
        android:layout_width="95dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textTimer"
        android:text="Mezičas"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSplit3"
        android:layout_width="95dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textTimer"
        android:text="Mezičas"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/split"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnStart"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnStart"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:editable="true"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/split2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/split"
        android:layout_below="@+id/split"
        android:editable="true"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/split3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/split2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/split2"
        android:editable="true"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/split4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/split3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/split3"
        android:editable="true"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/split5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/split4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/split4"
        android:editable="true"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/splitfinal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/split5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/split5"
        android:editable="true"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <com.startapp.android.publish.banner.Banner
        android:id="@+id/startAppBanner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

    </com.startapp.android.publish.banner.Banner>

</RelativeLayout>¨
```

LogCat:

```
05-10 19:39:58.147: E/EmbeddedLogger(1598): App crashed! Process: cz.miegl.stopky
05-10 19:39:58.147: E/EmbeddedLogger(1598): App crashed! Package: cz.miegl.stopky v1 (1.0)
05-10 19:39:58.147: E/EmbeddedLogger(1598): Application Label: Stopky
05-10 19:39:58.157: W/ActivityManager(1598):   Force finishing activity cz.miegl.stopky/.MainActivity
05-10 19:39:58.177: D/ViewRootImpl(1598): @@@- disable SystemServer HW acceleration
05-10 19:39:58.207: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(1444): <CreateImage:893>: Android Image
05-10 19:39:58.207: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(1444): <GetImageAttributes:1102>: RGBA_8888
05-10 19:39:58.567: D/WifiStateMachine(1598): fetchRssiAndLinkSpeedNative RSSI = -77
05-10 19:39:58.567: D/WifiStateMachine(1598): fetchRssiAndLinkSpeedNative send RSSIChange intent, newSignalLevel =2mLastSignalLevel = 0
05-10 19:39:58.667: D/PowerManagerService(1598): New lightsensor value:160, lcdValue:97
05-10 19:39:58.667: D/PowerManagerService(1598): lightSensorChangedLocked, buttonValue >= 0, mPowerState = 3
05-10 19:39:58.667: W/ActivityManager(1598): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{40efd450 cz.miegl.stopky/.MainActivity}
05-10 19:39:58.687: D/CAT(1804): CatService: Return current sInstance
05-10 19:39:58.707: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(1721): <ConfigWindowMatch:2078>: Format RGBA_8888.
05-10 19:39:58.797: D/OpenGLRenderer(1721): has fontRender patch
05-10 19:39:58.838: D/skia(1721): Decode special JPEG file
05-10 19:39:58.948: D/TileRenderer(1721): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-10 19:39:58.968: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(1444): <CreateImage:893>: Android Image
05-10 19:39:58.968: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(1444): <GetImageAttributes:1102>: RGBA_8888
05-10 19:39:58.968: D/ConnectivityService(1598): onUidRulesChanged(uid=10162, uidRules=0)
05-10 19:39:59.018: D/TileRenderer(1721): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-10 19:39:59.048: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(1444): <CreateImage:893>: Android Image
05-10 19:39:59.048: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(1444): <GetImageAttributes:1102>: RGBA_8888
05-10 19:39:59.188: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(1444): <CreateImage:893>: Android Image
05-10 19:39:59.188: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(1444): <GetImageAttributes:1102>: RGBA_8888
05-10 19:39:59.268: W/CpuWake(1598): >>releaseCpuPerfWakeLock
05-10 19:39:59.268: W/CpuWake(1598): <<releaseCpuPerfWakeLock
05-10 19:39:59.518: I/PowerManagerService-JNI(1598): [Stability] PowerManagerService_userActivity JNI pass power key event to PowerManagerService userActivity()
05-10 19:39:59.648: D/Process(15998): killProcess, pid=15998
05-10 19:39:59.648: D/Process(15998): dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
05-10 19:39:59.648: D/Process(15998): java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:599)
05-10 19:39:59.648: D/Process(15998): android.os.Process.killProcess(Process.java:807)
05-10 19:39:59.648: D/Process(15998): com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:104)
05-10 19:39:59.648: D/Process(15998): java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
05-10 19:39:59.648: D/Process(15998): java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
05-10 19:39:59.648: D/Process(15998): dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-10 19:39:59.648: I/Process(15998): Sending signal. PID: 15998 SIG: 9
05-10 19:39:59.678: W/InputManagerService(1598): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@417efa58
05-10 19:39:59.678: I/ActivityManager(1598): Process cz.miegl.stopky (pid 15998) has died.
05-10 19:39:59.909: D/memalloc(1598): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x591d7000 size:10076160 offset:9707520
05-10 19:39:59.909: D/memalloc(1598): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x58a0c000 size:8171520 offset:7802880
05-10 19:40:00.769: E/EmbeddedLogger(1598): App crashed! Process: cz.miegl.stopky
05-10 19:40:00.769: E/EmbeddedLogger(1598): App crashed! Package: cz.miegl.stopky v1 (1.0)
05-10 19:40:00.769: E/EmbeddedLogger(1598): Application Label: Stopky
05-10 19:40:00.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16021): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-10 19:40:00.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16021): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{cz.miegl.stopky/cz.miegl.stopky.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
05-10 19:40:00.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16021):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2205)
05-10 19:40:00.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16021):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2240)
05-10 19:40:00.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16021):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
05-10 19:40:00.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16021):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1262)
05-10 19:40:00.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16021):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-10 19:40:00.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16021):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
05-10 19:40:00.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16021):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4977)
05-10 19:40:00.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16021):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-10 19:40:00.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16021):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-10 19:40:00.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16021):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-10 19:40:00.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16021):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-10 19:40:00.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16021):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-10 19:40:00.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16021): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
05-10 19:40:00.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16021):    at cz.miegl.stopky.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
05-10 19:40:00.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16021):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4538)
05-10 19:40:00.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16021):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
05-10 19:40:00.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16021):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
05-10 19:40:00.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16021):    ... 11 more
05-10 19:40:00.769: W/ActivityManager(1598):   Force finishing activity cz.miegl.stopky/.MainActivity
05-10 19:40:00.789: D/ViewRootImpl(1598): @@@- disable SystemServer HW acceleration
05-10 19:40:00.839: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(1444): <CreateImage:893>: Android Image
05-10 19:40:00.839: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(1444): <GetImageAttributes:1102>: RGBA_8888
05-10 19:40:01.290: W/ActivityManager(1598): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{40fd92e8 cz.miegl.stopky/.MainActivity}
05-10 19:40:01.300: D/CAT(1804): CatService: Return current sInstance
05-10 19:40:01.320: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(1721): <ConfigWindowMatch:2078>: Format RGBA_8888.
05-10 19:40:01.380: D/OpenGLRenderer(1721): has fontRender patch
05-10 19:40:01.490: D/TileRenderer(1721): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-10 19:40:01.510: D/ConnectivityService(1598): onUidRulesChanged(uid=10162, uidRules=0)
05-10 19:40:01.520: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(1444): <CreateImage:893>: Android Image
05-10 19:40:01.520: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(1444): <GetImageAttributes:1102>: RGBA_8888
05-10 19:40:01.580: D/WifiStateMachine(1598): fetchRssiAndLinkSpeedNative RSSI = -80
05-10 19:40:01.580: D/WifiStateMachine(1598): BroadcastRSSIForIMS, newrssi =-80 , oldRssi= -77
05-10 19:40:01.630: D/TileRenderer(1721): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-10 19:40:01.640: I/PowerManagerService-JNI(1598): [Stability] PowerManagerService_userActivity JNI pass power key event to PowerManagerService userActivity()
05-10 19:40:01.660: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(1444): <CreateImage:893>: Android Image
05-10 19:40:01.660: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(1444): <GetImageAttributes:1102>: RGBA_8888
05-10 19:40:01.800: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(1444): <CreateImage:893>: Android Image
05-10 19:40:01.800: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(1444): <GetImageAttributes:1102>: RGBA_8888
05-10 19:40:02.121: W/CpuWake(1598): >>releaseCpuPerfWakeLock
05-10 19:40:02.121: W/CpuWake(1598): <<releaseCpuPerfWakeLock
05-10 19:40:02.171: I/PowerManagerService-JNI(1598): [Stability] PowerManagerService_userActivity JNI pass power key event to PowerManagerService userActivity()
05-10 19:40:02.331: D/Process(16021): killProcess, pid=16021
05-10 19:40:02.341: D/Process(16021): dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
05-10 19:40:02.341: D/Process(16021): java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:599)
05-10 19:40:02.341: D/Process(16021): android.os.Process.killProcess(Process.java:807)
05-10 19:40:02.341: D/Process(16021): com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:104)
05-10 19:40:02.341: D/Process(16021): java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
05-10 19:40:02.341: D/Process(16021): java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
05-10 19:40:02.341: D/Process(16021): dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-10 19:40:02.341: I/Process(16021): Sending signal. PID: 16021 SIG: 9
05-10 19:40:02.341: W/InputManagerService(1598): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4133e270
05-10 19:40:02.361: I/ActivityManager(1598): Process cz.miegl.stopky (pid 16021) has died.
05-10 19:40:03.842: E/EmbeddedLogger(1598): App crashed! Process: cz.miegl.stopky
05-10 19:40:03.842: E/EmbeddedLogger(1598): App crashed! Package: cz.miegl.stopky v1 (1.0)
05-10 19:40:03.842: E/EmbeddedLogger(1598): Application Label: Stopky
05-10 19:40:03.842: E/AndroidRuntime(16044): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-10 19:40:03.842: E/AndroidRuntime(16044): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{cz.miegl.stopky/cz.miegl.stopky.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
05-10 19:40:03.842: E/AndroidRuntime(16044):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2205)
05-10 19:40:03.842: E/AndroidRuntime(16044):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2240)
05-10 19:40:03.842: E/AndroidRuntime(16044):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
05-10 19:40:03.842: E/AndroidRuntime(16044):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1262)
05-10 19:40:03.842: E/AndroidRuntime(16044):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-10 19:40:03.842: E/AndroidRuntime(16044):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
05-10 19:40:03.842: E/AndroidRuntime(16044):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4977)
05-10 19:40:03.842: E/AndroidRuntime(16044):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-10 19:40:03.842: E/AndroidRuntime(16044):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-10 19:40:03.842: E/AndroidRuntime(16044):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-10 19:40:03.842: E/AndroidRuntime(16044):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-10 19:40:03.842: E/AndroidRuntime(16044):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-10 19:40:03.842: E/AndroidRuntime(16044): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
05-10 19:40:03.842: E/AndroidRuntime(16044):    at cz.miegl.stopky.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
05-10 19:40:03.842: E/AndroidRuntime(16044):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4538)
05-10 19:40:03.842: E/AndroidRuntime(16044):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
05-10 19:40:03.842: E/AndroidRuntime(16044):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
05-10 19:40:03.842: E/AndroidRuntime(16044):    ... 11 more
05-10 19:40:03.842: W/ActivityManager(1598):   Force finishing activity cz.miegl.stopky/.MainActivity
05-10 19:40:03.882: D/ViewRootImpl(1598): @@@- disable SystemServer HW acceleration
05-10 19:40:03.912: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(1444): <CreateImage:893>: Android Image
05-10 19:40:03.912: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(1444): <GetImageAttributes:1102>: RGBA_8888
05-10 19:40:04.113: D/BatteryService(1598): updateBatteryStats
```

And my MainActivity.java file:

```
package cz.miegl.stopky;

import com.startapp.android.publish.StartAppAd;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView textTimer;
private Button startButton;
private Button pauseButton;
private Button splitButton;
private Button resumeButton;
private long startTime = 0L;
private Handler myHandler = new Handler();
long timeInMillies = 0L;
long resume = 0L;
long timeSwap = 0L;
long finalTime = 0L;
public long text = finalTime;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
StartAppAd.init(this, "104242833 ", "204230324");
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

textTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTimer);

startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View view) {
startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
myHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerMethod, 0);
TextView split = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.split);
split.setText("");
TextView split2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.split2);
split2.setText("");
TextView split3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.split3);
split3.setText("");
TextView split4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.split4);
split4.setText("");
TextView split5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.split5);
split5.setText("");
TextView splitfinal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.splitfinal);
splitfinal.setText("");
View btnSplit = findViewById(R.id.btnSplit);
btnSplit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
View btnSplit2 = findViewById(R.id.btnSplit2);
btnSplit2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
View btnSplit3 = findViewById(R.id.btnSplit3);
btnSplit3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
View btnSplit4 = findViewById(R.id.btnSplit4);
btnSplit4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
View btnSplit5 = findViewById(R.id.btnSplit5);
btnSplit5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
View btnResume = findViewById(R.id.btnResume);
btnResume.setVisibility(View.GONE);
View btnPause = findViewById(R.id.btnPause);
btnPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
});

resumeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnResume);
resumeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View view) {
startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - finalTime;
myHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerMethod, 0);
View btnResume = findViewById(R.id.btnResume);
btnResume.setVisibility(View.GONE);
View btnPause = findViewById(R.id.btnPause);
btnPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
});

pauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPause);
pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View view) {
startTime += timeInMillies;
myHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerMethod);
View btnResume = findViewById(R.id.btnResume);
btnResume.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
View btnPause = findViewById(R.id.btnPause);
btnPause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
int seconds = (int) (finalTime / 1000);
int minutes = seconds / 60;
seconds = seconds % 60;
int milliseconds = (int) (finalTime % 1000);
TextView splitfinal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.splitfinal);
splitfinal.setText("Čas: " + minutes + ":" +  String.format("%02d", seconds) + ":" + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));

}
});

splitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSplit);
splitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View view) {
int seconds = (int) (finalTime / 1000);
int minutes = seconds / 60;
seconds = seconds % 60;
int milliseconds = (int) (finalTime % 1000);
TextView split = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.split);
split.setText("1. " + minutes + ":" +  String.format("%02d", seconds) + ":" + String.format("%03d", milliseconds) + " (Mezičas)");
View btnSplit = findViewById(R.id.btnSplit);
btnSplit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
View btnSplit2 = findViewById(R.id.btnSplit2);
btnSplit2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
View btnSplit3 = findViewById(R.id.btnSplit3);
btnSplit3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
View btnSplit4 = findViewById(R.id.btnSplit4);
btnSplit4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
View btnSplit5 = findViewById(R.id.btnSplit5);
btnSplit5.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}
});

splitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSplit2);
splitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View view) {
int seconds = (int) (finalTime / 1000);
int minutes = seconds / 60;
seconds = seconds % 60;
int milliseconds = (int) (finalTime % 1000);
TextView split = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.split2);
split.setText("2. " + minutes + ":" +  String.format("%02d", seconds) + ":" + String.format("%03d", milliseconds) + " (Mezičas)");
View btnSplit = findViewById(R.id.btnSplit);
btnSplit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
View btnSplit2 = findViewById(R.id.btnSplit2);
btnSplit2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
View btnSplit3 = findViewById(R.id.btnSplit3);
btnSplit3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
View btnSplit4 = findViewById(R.id.btnSplit4);
btnSplit4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
View btnSplit5 = findViewById(R.id.btnSplit5);
btnSplit5.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}
});

splitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSplit3);
splitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View view) {
int seconds = (int) (finalTime / 1000);
int minutes = seconds / 60;
seconds = seconds % 60;
int milliseconds = (int) (finalTime % 1000);
TextView split = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.split3);
split.setText("3. " + minutes + ":" +  String.format("%02d", seconds) + ":" + String.format("%03d", milliseconds) + " (Mezičas)");
View btnSplit = findViewById(R.id.btnSplit);
btnSplit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
View btnSplit2 = findViewById(R.id.btnSplit2);
btnSplit2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
View btnSplit3 = findViewById(R.id.btnSplit3);
btnSplit3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
View btnSplit4 = findViewById(R.id.btnSplit4);
btnSplit4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
View btnSplit5 = findViewById(R.id.btnSplit5);
btnSplit5.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}
});

splitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSplit4);
splitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View view) {
int seconds = (int) (finalTime / 1000);
int minutes = seconds / 60;
seconds = seconds % 60;
int milliseconds = (int) (finalTime % 1000);
TextView split = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.split4);
split.setText("4. " + minutes + ":" +  String.format("%02d", seconds) + ":" + String.format("%03d", milliseconds) + " (Mezičas)");
View btnSplit = findViewById(R.id.btnSplit);
btnSplit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
View btnSplit2 = findViewById(R.id.btnSplit2);
btnSplit2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
View btnSplit3 = findViewById(R.id.btnSplit3);
btnSplit3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
View btnSplit4 = findViewById(R.id.btnSplit4);
btnSplit4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
View btnSplit5 = findViewById(R.id.btnSplit5);
btnSplit5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
});

splitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSplit5);
splitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View view) {
int seconds = (int) (finalTime / 1000);
int minutes = seconds / 60;
seconds = seconds % 60;
int milliseconds = (int) (finalTime % 1000);
TextView split = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.split5);
split.setText("5. " + minutes + ":" +  String.format("%02d", seconds) + ":" + String.format("%03d", milliseconds) + " (Mezičas)");
View btnSplit = findViewById(R.id.btnSplit);
btnSplit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
View btnSplit2 = findViewById(R.id.btnSplit2);
btnSplit2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
View btnSplit3 = findViewById(R.id.btnSplit3);
btnSplit3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
View btnSplit4 = findViewById(R.id.btnSplit4);
btnSplit4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
View btnSplit5 = findViewById(R.id.btnSplit5);
btnSplit5.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}
});
}


private Runnable updateTimerMethod = new Runnable() {

public void run() {
timeInMillies = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()- startTime;
finalTime = timeSwap + timeInMillies;

int seconds = (int) (finalTime / 1000);
int minutes = seconds / 60;
seconds = seconds % 60;
int milliseconds = (int) (finalTime % 1000);
textTimer.setText("" + minutes + ":"
+ String.format("%02d", seconds) + ":"
+ String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
myHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
}

};

}
```

Please help me. I do not know what to do. Thank you in advance.

Please answer :)

Comment: What is this stacktrace?

Comment: The LogCat window contents

Comment: Ok, added the LogCat messages

Comment: Clean and rebuild. Seems like binary XML files and generated R.java are out of sync.

Comment: What's in your MainActivity.java:37?

Comment: OK, added the java file. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean and rebuild.

Looks like the `ClassCastException` comes from this line

```
startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
```

and `btnStart` is a `Button` in your XML but it comes out as `TextView`.

Sometimes when editing the XML files, the resource identifiers in compiled XML files and `R.java` become out of sync. Cleaning the project ensures the files are rebuilt and resource identifiers are pointing to the correct things.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not know what to do. XML me more and more surprises! :D Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely in your java code.  Are you trying to use (Button)findViewById(R.id.textTimer)?  You can't do that, it isn't a button.  Cast it to a TextView instead.  Likely a copy paste bug

Comment: No. I using Button as a Button and TextView as a TextView.